# xcode command line to configure "embed frameworks"

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

As showed in the screen above, I couldn't find any `xcodebuild` command line to add/remove the embed frameworks, is there any way we can do so via command line (to remove or add the line)? As I need to automate the build process.

Answer (score 1):

For conditionally embedding frameworks to your app you should make a script under Build Phases that copies your dynamic library to Frameworks folder of your app and then sign it e.g.:

```
# Path to your framework to copy. You must have two compiled versions: Debug(arm64, x86_64) and Release(arm64).
FRAMEWORK=".../$CONFIGURATION/MyFramework.framework"

# Frameworks folder of your app
NAME=$(basename $FRAMEWORK)
DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/$NAME

# Copy (if needed) and sign
if [ ! -d $DESTINATION ]; then
    cp -r $FRAMEWORK $DESTINATION
    codesign --force --sign ${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY} ${OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS:-} --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements $DESTINATION
fi
```

For `xcframework` you can specify subfolder path in additional for a target arch:

```
# Release device only
if [ $PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH == "arm64" ]; then
    FRAMEWORK=".../MyFramework.xcframework/ios-arm64/MyFramework.framework"
fi
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, actually my XCode project was scaffold by other tools, when it is scaffold, the embed framework entries is already there, so basically, my intention is to remove it, but remain them as statically linked. Is there a way to remove such entries there via command line?